# jQuery Lazy Loading: Call a Javascript function after image was lazy loaded

Tags: jquery, image, lazy-loading

I'm using Mika Tuupola's jQuery Lazy Loading.

Is it possible to call a function, every time after an image is lazy loaded.

What I'm intending to do is to track the number of times an image was viewed. So, if the image was lazy loaded, it means the user had seen the image and I'll increment a counter on my database by 1 by doing a HTTP GET on the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source, I found two undocumented callback options: `appear` is called before loading an image, `load` is called after the image is loaded. The parameters are the image element, the number of unloaded images, and the options object.

Comment: It wasn't obvious that this is what those options do! I was very close to recommending that you write an `onload` handler that checked whether the src was the placeholder image or not.